# With htaccess pass file name of an xml file as a var to sitemap generating php file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I want to have an xml filename redirect to a php file passing the name of the file without the appending `xml` as a var. Thus, if the file name is `something.xml` it would pass to a php file and pass a var: `something`

Examples (top is original URL; bottom is new URL):

```
https://www.someurl.com/somename.xml
https://someurl.com/files/sitemapper.php?var=somename

https://www.someurl.com/anothername.xml
https://someurl.com/files/sitemapper.php?var=anothername

https://www.someurl.com/willikers.xml
https://someurl.com/files/sitemapper.php?var=willikers
```

Comment: That's about as basic as rewriting gets, so surely you have an attempt to show us?

Answer (score 1):

SO user CBroe intimidated me into figuring this out on my own. In this solution, I'm directing from xml files within a folder zm as I wanted this rule to not affect other xml files already in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^zm/([\w-]+)\.xml$ /files/sitemapper.php?var=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: He wasn't "intimidating" you. He was asking you to abide by the rules for this site. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info particularly the 2nd bullet point under "How To Ask"

Comment: I didn't know the rule. Sorry. My "intimidated" comment was intended only as a playful tongue in check recognition that I'd been busted for not trying hard enough. I searched for the answer on SO initially. Not finding it, I thought I'd be "contributing to the cause" to post the question. Again, I thought I'd only broken a social standard by not wrestling with it more on my own at first. I didn't know of a rule. Now I know. Thank you for informing me.